# Accidentally uninstalled play store from rooted phone

Tags: lg

I have rooted my LG E610 (Optimus L5) recently. Accidentally my play store apk is uninstalled and deleted. What should I do ??
Android version: 4.0.3

Comment: You can try to replace the deleted apk withthe one from https://opengapps.org/ or you delete all Google apps and install the complete Open GApps package (e.g. nano, micro or what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I've had some previous experience using this device and if I remember correctly,
You have 2 options
1 - Reinstall just the 4.0.3 Google play store application

```
system/app/phonesky.apk
```

2 - Install a fresh firmware
[LG E610 L5 Firmware's](https://lg-firmwares.com/lg-e610-firmwares/#tab=firmwares)

The fresh Firmware installation WILL be an upgrade to android 4.3, This will change your kernel and a downgrade is very difficult after that.

I'm fairly sure I ran KitKat via CyanogenMod 11..
The cyanogen build is stable for my every day usage and the benefit of KitKat goes without saying.
[firmware I used - I think... it's been a while.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/optimus-l3-l5-l7/orig-development/l5-unofficial-cyanogenmod11-r1-t3130325)

You should already have a Custom Recovery !
Never gain root access on any device, without a way to make a backup... You need to have backup and restore capability with any rooted device.

So mainly, Grab a gapps package for 4.0.3 ( or just the phonesky.apk and phonesky.odex files )

Or firmware upgrade.....  I just firmware upgraded ... I think KitKat comes with the HotSpot settings and few others that help out :)